# Remove all white space from Image with Base64 and Cors

Tags: javascript, image, cors, base64

My idea is to grab an image from an URL, send it through a cors proxy, convert that to base64, then remove the white space from the image and replace that with a transparent background. I have managed to do that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ajax Image</title>

    <style>
        body {
            background: darkslategrey;
        }

        .text {
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Original -->
    <h3 class="text">Original</h3>
    <img src="" id="original">

    <!-- Modified -->
    <h3 class="text">Modified</h3>
    <canvas id="modified"></canvas>

    <script src="../CommonLinkedFiles/jquery3_2_1.js"></script>
    <script>

        var stockSymbol = "extr";
        var logoUrl = "https://storage.googleapis.com/iex/api/logos/" + stockSymbol.toUpperCase() + ".png";

        // Converting URL to Base64 with the use of a proxy
        var getDataUri = function (targetUrl, callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onload = function () {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function () {
                    callback(reader.result);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
            };
            var proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
            xhr.open('GET', proxyUrl + targetUrl);
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.send();
        };

        // Returns Base 64 of image
        getDataUri(logoUrl, function (base64) {
            console.log('RESULT:', base64);

            //original
            $("#original").attr("src", base64);

            var canvas = document.getElementById("modified"),
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                image = document.getElementById("original");

            canvas.height = canvas.width = 128;
            ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);

            var imgd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 128, 128),
                pix = imgd.data,
                newColor = {r:0,g:0,b:0, a:0};

            for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i <n; i += 4) {
                var r = pix[i],
                    g = pix[i+1],
                    b = pix[i+2];

                if(r == 255&& g == 255 && b == 255){
                    // Change the white to the new color.
                    pix[i] = newColor.r;
                    pix[i+1] = newColor.g;
                    pix[i+2] = newColor.b;
                    pix[i+3] = newColor.a;
                }
            }

            ctx.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

You can see here at: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xq32wge9/16/)

My question is how do I remove all of the white space given any image.

Edit: Keith Solved the image by adding on onload function.

Comment: Even if I set the background to blue as in the Jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry, let me see if I can be more clear. I have the color set to dark slate grey, why do I have to change the background color and refresh the page in order for the modified image to reappear.

Comment: AH! I did misunderstand. You mean to see the image *at all*, not merely the transparent sections. Is that right?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I meant to see the image at all

Comment: `$("#original").attr("src", base64);`  Even if using a data uri, you still need to wait for the image to load..  Try placing the next part of your code inside `$("#original").on("load", function () { /* rest of code */ } );`

Comment: Keith Thank you that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tinkering, I figured out that all of the "white" pixels were not exactly white so I so modifying the if statement it searched for all of near white pixels:`if(r >= 250&& g >= 250 && b >= 250){`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xq32wge9/49/)